# Log in to Facebook's Graph API with an already-generated access token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

We have a Facebook app, and through it we pull in posts and images from our company's Facebook account to an interface for later use, with the old API. Several people in the company use this interface.

We're upgrading to the new Graph API and since there are many people using the interface, I would like to generate an access token from a single user's login credentials in the background, without the whole login URL and window. We are using the PHP SDK.

Is it possible to log in a user programmatically on a button click, for example, and continue with API calls? Or will every user need to login with the popup window to be able to import posts? I assume I would then need to send in the login credentials and permissions array as well...

I've tried to add in the `access_token` here:

```
$facebook = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => {app-id},
    'app_secret' => {app-secret} ,
    'default_access_token' => {access-token} ,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v5.0',
]);
// Can you get around the redirect with JavaScript helper here instead?
$helper = $facebook->getRedirectLoginHelper(); 

try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

if (!isset($accessToken)) {
    if ($helper->getError()) {
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo 'Unauthorized';
    } else {
        // This is the response I always get sending in the access_token
        header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
        echo 'Bad request';
    }
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-Login without user interaction is not possible, that would be a major security issue. You have to authorize as a user who is logged in.

You can only create an Extended Page Token as a user who manages the Page and store it - it will be valid for about 60 days.

Alternatively, you can apply for [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS) and just use an App Access Token - that is, if the Page is not restricted by age or location.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It would just be a hassle to have everyone input the dummy account's user info every time, especially if they are logged into Facebook themselves in another tab

Comment: that would be the only way though, you would most likely not get page public content access if it is just for your own company page.

Comment: You mean that Facebook likely won't grant us Page Public Content Access since we aren't dealing with other users' content?

Comment: because you only need access to your own company page